# Excel Password Recovery

Tags: microsoft-excel, password-recovery

I have forgotten my Excel password the file was in Win 2003 version. I tried many tools for recovering back the password but none of them helped me.  Please help me…

Comment: Can you explain what tools you used etc please?

Answer (score 0):

I used to use this tool on Word and Excel 2013 files, it worked OK
[Advanced Office Password Recovery](http://elcomsoft.com/aopr.html)